# VB.NET - SqlException: Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, backup, sqlexception

I want to backup my database using Linq to SQL:

```
 Dim sql As String = "BACKUP DATABASE SeaCowDatabase TO DISK = _ 
 '" + sfd.FileName + "'"
 db.ExecuteCommand(sql)
```

But instead, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'SeaCowDatabase'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
>      at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteCommand(String command, Object[] parameters)
>      at SeaCow.Main.Ribbon_Save_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Daniel\My Programs\Visual Basic\SeaCow\SeaCow\SeaCow\Main.vb:line 595

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This could be a permissions issue.  I would verify that you can access the database from your program first.

Comment: I am able to access the database with my program.

Comment: The next question is why in the world would you ever use .net to backup a database.  This can be a job on the sql box or even a sproc.  Let the database handle the data.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure about these things:

1. This database actually exists
2. The login and user that you use have rights to backup database

Comment: I know the database exists since my program retrieves and stores information from it. I am not sure about the login part.